# confused with design and building ASP.Net MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, uml

**Hello everybody**,

I am a student in computer engineering and this is my first question in stackoverflow.

I just started an internship at a company that makes software development and asked me to design and build a web application with ASP.Net MVC makes the management of its IT projects (task management), planning meetings... The application must also provide a dashboard summarizing some activity of the company.

I always mess with UML .. in fact I have several questions and I find no clear answers.

the design of a  MVC application is the same as a three-tier application? or the first must follow special design models?
I do not really know how to approach the design .. neither the steps by which he must go ..nor in what way that will help me.

Well, I hope so as I do not talk nonsense
thank you all

Answer (score 1):

the design of a MVC application is the same as a three-tier application?

No, ASP.NET MVC (MVC in general) is strictly a presentation-tier design pattern. ASP.NET MVC does not care if you have a Business layer or data-access layer at all. This is why you will see in many examples that the controller directly connects to a database.

Comment: OK.. I see 
But to make more clear my problem: I do not know how to begin to realize this project 

What should i do first ? 
Use case diagrams, class diagrams etc.. or another approach? 
And how UML may helps me ??

Comment: Oh, you are asking a process question, not an implementation question. Do you have requirements or are you making the requirements as well? If you have requirements, then I suggest building use cases that in total fulfill all of the requirements documented. From there you can create whatever UML structures you feel are helpful (use case diagram, activity diagram, sequence diagram, etc.).

Comment: I'm making the requirements as well. 

So i can understand that when building the App, all the work done before with UML is independent of what is the architecture of the App ?  

I'm sorry if my question was not clear. I'm not Anglo-Saxon I make an effort to express myself well

Comment: Well then my advice is Requirements -> Use Cases (written) -> Use Case Diagrams -> Activity Diagram, Sequence Diagram

Comment: And the classes diagram ?? No need ?